# Regex with condition

Tags: regex, vb.net

In Vb.net i have 4 type of lines

```
line 1:
<p>11.<span>this is</span>some text</p>
line2:
<p>a)<span>this is</span>some text</p>
line3:
<p><span>random string</span>12.<span>this is </span>some text</p>
line4:
<p><span>random string</span>a)<span>this is </span>some text</p>
```

I want output as `this is some text`

i am using `regex (?<=<p.*>.*<span.*>.*?>)(.*)(?=</p>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p>.*<span>(.*?)\s*</span>(.*)</p>
```

and replace with `\1 \2`.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD7cG1/1).

Comment: please help me understand replace \1 \2

Comment: `\1` and `\2` refer to the first and second [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) respectively. Basically it allows you to access part of the text that the pattern has matched, which, in this case, is the text inside and after the `span` tag.